# Querying a row with times - postgresql

Tags: javascript, psql

At present I have a simple query that will get me fixtures from my DB that belong to a particular league and are then ordered by kick off time.

```
response = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM fixtures WHERE league_name = $1 ORDER BY kick_off ASC', [leagueName]);
```

Now if I want to expand on this and return the fixtures that are upcoming or inplay (so a 2 hour buffer on top of the time now lets say), what queries should I be looking at? The `kick_off` time is stored as a `VARCHAR`, so `15:00` or `19:00`.

I was thinking about grabbing the time from the users browser with javascript and passing that and doing a comparison that way but timezones would make this tricky right? So my thinking is do it on the server so I know it's consistent ?

I am not sure on the queries though

If I am wrong with my assumptions happy to be corrected to learn here

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing a time as a varchar makes this unnecessarily hard (borderline impossible). The reason is that your DB doesn't understand it as a time, so you'd really have to roll your own time-sorting functions. Ugh.

What you need to do is change kick_off to be a TIME, TIMESTAMP, or even TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE. Then your query look would like:

```
SELECT * FROM fixtures 
   WHERE league_name = $1 
   AND kick_off > NOW()-interval '2 hour' 
   AND kick_off < NOW()+interval '2 hour' 
   ORDER BY kick_off ASC;
```

No need to muck about with the browser's time, your DB already knows what time it is!

(note, I'm assumeing a game takes 2 hours, but I'm not sure what the sport in question is, and even if I was, I'm not sure on the average game length. Change the now()- to suit.)

Comment: Thank you, had a feeling I should have stored the kick off time as Timestamp, will correct that. Thank you for posting a clear explanation and answer too, makes sense and I have already learned from it